# Second smallest number in array - incorrect output

Tags: java, arrays, integer

So this has been bugging me for a hour and a half and it's getting really annoying. I'm not sure what's the issue because I've rechecked several times my code, I've googled and searched for other ways or if I did something wrong and I still don't see anything.

This is an excerpt from my code:

```
    // MAX AND MIN NUMBER
    int maxnum = array[0];
    int minnum = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > maxnum) {
            maxnum = array[i];
        } else if (array[i] < minnum) {
            minnum = array[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Maximum number is " + maxnum + ", minimum is " + minnum + ".");
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // SECOND SMALLEST NUMBER
    int secondnum = array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == minnum) {
            secondnum = minnum;
        } else if (array[i] < minnum) {
            secondnum = minnum;
            minnum = array[i];
        } else if (array[i] < secondnum) {
            secondnum = array[i];
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Second smallest number is " + secondnum + ".");
```

array[i] is an input from the user. At the beginning, the program asks you to enter how many numbers you wish to enter and then you proceed to enter them.
I put in five and I enter five numbers but my second smallest number is the same as my smallest number. Sometimes I get a correct answer.
Any ideas?

EDIT:
Works with user3591111's help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any `if` statements comparing the `minimum` number with the `secondnum (second min)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first for you can start in i =1 in the second for try.

```
int secondnum = maxnum;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] != minnum && array[i] <secondnum  ) 
       secondnum = array[i];

}
```

This wont work if you have repeated numbers because your small can be equal to your second small for that you will need to store the location of your small number and in the if change to `if ((array[i] != minnum || smallPos != i) && array[i] <secondnum  )`